# How download content post with link youtube

Tags: c#, windows-8

I'm working on an application for Windows 8, which downloads content from blog (wordpress RSS ). The content is post with title and a link to youtube. How can i perform a download?

This app wants a function to download blog content (post), which link yt and title (I'm trying dictonary, but app addition different title and link.)

```
private ObservableCollection<FeedData> feeds = new ObservableCollection<FeedData>();
public ObservableCollection<FeedData> Feeds
{
    get
    {
        return this.feeds;
    }
}
public async Task GetFeedsAsync()
{
    Task<FeedData> feed1 = this.GetFeedAsync("http://urlblog/?feed=rss2");
    this.Feeds.Add(await feed1);
}

private async Task<FeedData> GetFeedAsync(string feedUriString)
{

    SyndicationClient client = new SyndicationClient();
    Uri feedUri = new Uri(feedUriString);
    try
    {
        SyndicationFeed feed = await client.RetrieveFeedAsync(feedUri);
        FeedData feedData = new FeedData();
        feedData.Title = feed.Title.Text;
        if (feed.Subtitle != null && feed.Subtitle.Text != null)
        {
            feedData.Description = feed.Subtitle.Text;
        }
        // Use the date of the latest post as the last updated date.
        feedData.PubDate = feed.Items[0].PublishedDate.DateTime;

        foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items)
        {
            FeedItem feedItem = new FeedItem();
            feedItem.Title = item.Title.Text;
            feedItem.PubDate = item.PublishedDate.DateTime;
            feedItem.Author = item.Authors[0].Name;
            if (feed.SourceFormat == SyndicationFormat.Atom10)
            {
                Match m = Regex.Match(
                   item.Summary.Text, @"youtu(?:\.be|be\.com)/(?:.*v(?:/|=)|(?:.*/)?)([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

                feedItem.Content = m.Groups[0].ToString();
                feedItem.Content = m.Value;
                feedItem.Link = new Uri("url" + item.Id);
            }
            else if (feed.SourceFormat == SyndicationFormat.Rss20)
            {
                Match m = Regex.Match(
                item.Summary.Text, @"youtu(?:\.be|be\.com)/(?:.*v(?:/|=)|(?:.*/)?)([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)");
                feedItem.Content = m.Groups[1].ToString();
                feedItem.Content = m.Value;
                feedItem.Link = item.Links[0].Uri;
            }
            feedData.Items.Add(feedItem);
        }
        return feedData;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**FeedItem.cs**

```
public class FeedItem
{        
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }      
    public Uri Link { get; set; }
    public DateTime PubDate { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }    
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by download?  You want to show the video or actually capture the contents.  The latter is, I believe, against their [terms and conditions](http://www.youtube.com/t/terms), and I believe you can only show it via their player on via the website.

Comment: I want download link film and title post. In application those film been view, in listView. The most important for me is download video and link ( post have video and title )

Comment: ok, so is the syndication code above not working?  What errors are you getting? Assuming the FeedItem class is being populated, that contains the information you need, correct?